# How come i can separate the element from its content and change their separate sizes when its a text element, but not when its an image?

Tags: html, css

What i mean is this. If my code is this:

```
<div class="text-element">

<p>Text</p>

</div>
```

Now, i can separate the element

from its content, in this case, the text, and create space between them, and change their individual size. I can change the size of the element and the size of the text. But i can't do the same thing for  element.

If the code is:

```
<div class="img-element">

<img src="mycat.jpg">

</div>
```

Now, when i change the size of the img, the size of the entire element changes, and when i change the size of the element, the image changes. I can't separate the element from the content, in this case, the image, and change their sizes separately like i can for other tags. Why is that? I want to separate the two, and create space between the  element and the actual image inside, and then work on both separately. Why is it that i can do that with other elements but not with "img" element?

Comment: Can we see your CSS? Also did you make sure to give the img tag a property of display:block? That usually resolves placement issues.

Comment: I am using CSS, what are you talking about? I didn't post any CSS because there is nothing to post. I tried using display flex on both the parent and the child element, and it doesn't work. Changing the height of the img element just changes the image itself. Changing the size of the parent element changes the space between the img and the larger block. What i want to do is change the img element size and the image inside of it. How do i do that?